# Remove half the points to minimize variance

Tags: optimization, variance

I have a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and I'm trying to find the subset of $\frac{n}{2}$ points with the smallest variance.

It can be shown that there exists a point in the set such that if we take the closest $\frac{n}{2}$ points closest to it we'll get a 2-approximation (i.e. a set with a variance at most twice the optimal) however I'm not interested in an approximation method but an optimal solution.

The obvious method to get an optimal solution would be to check any possible subset of size $\frac{n}{2}$ but then the time complexity would be exponential in $n$ and it won't be practical to run it.

So is there any way to solve this faster?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "variance"?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro sum of squared distances to the mean.

Comment: How large is $n$?

Comment: If you choose any point and then choose the $n/2$ points near it and then iteratively try to replace points in the set with points out of the set that reduces variance, you can get a decent approx. Repeat this for all $n$ initial spots (or just random initial assignments) and choose the smallest and you’d get a very good approximation quickly. Your actual optimal problem seems very similar to 2-means clustering which is np-hard.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg around 20-100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many comments said it sounds NP-hard but it's actually not (at least not in $n$, maybe it's NP-hard in $d$). We can solve it by doing something very similar to Voronoi Diagrams. We can pass an hyper plane between every pair of points which passes in the mean of them and is perpendicular to the line between them, each such hyper plane cuts the $R^d$ space into two parts one closer to the first point and one closer to the second points. That means all the reigons created by those hyperplanes (it can be shown to be $O\left(n^d\right)$ reigons) are the reigons that satisfies that regardless of which point you choose inside this reigon if you take the closest $n/2$ points to it (or any precentage of points fpr that matter not nesserily 50%) it will be the same $n/2$ points (since otherwise we would need to be in the other side of at least one of the hyperplanes). That means we can take an arbitrary point from each reigon compute the closest $n/2$ points and compute it's center of mass (mean) and the cost of the average, since the optimal point is in one of the reigons one of those closest $n/2$ points will be the same as in the optimal solution and meaning the optimal solution will be one of those centers of mass.

There is a naive way of computing those reigons that for constant $d$ will take $O\left(n^2\right)$ for each reigon (by computing the intersection of all the half spaces of this reigons) and this will give us a total running time of:

$$O\left(n^d\cdot n^2+n^d\cdot n\right)=O\left(n^{d+2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Variance in $\mathbb R^d$ is a sum of coordinate variances. For a sample of size $m$ and coordinate $x$:
$$
m s_x^2 = \sum_i (x_i-\bar x)^2 = \sum_i x_i^2 - m\bar x^2 = \sum_i x_i^2 - m\left(\sum_i \frac{x_i}m\right)^2 = \sum_i x_i^2-\frac1m\sum_i x_i^2-\frac2m\sum_{i>j}x_ix_j=\\
\frac{m-1}{m}\sum_i x_i^2 -\frac2m\sum_{i>j}x_ix_j.
$$

Thus, if you construct a triangular matrix:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
(m-1)x_1^2 & -2x_1x_2 & -2x_1x_3 & \cdots& -2x_1x_n \\
0 & (m-1)x_2^2 & -2x_2x_3 & \cdots & -2x_2x_n \\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots& \vdots\\
0&0&0&\cdots&(m-1)x_n^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then the goal is to keep $m$ rows/columns, so the sum is the least. If you have $d>1$, then you should add other coordinates to the matrix: $(m-1)(x_i^2+y_i^2+z_i^2)$. It would take $O(n^2d)$ to construct the matrix and $O(n^2)$ to remove $n/2$ largest rows/columns. It might still be impossible if $n=10^9$, but at least it's not exponential.

Comment: How are you removing the largest $n/2$ in quadratic time? Which rows you’ve removed affect which columns are remaining, so a simple greedy remove the largest row sum remaining isn’t sufficient to guarantee the smallest remaining variance (although it would be a decent approximation).

Comment: You are right, I forgot $\log n$ part. You can do it in $O(n^2\log n)$ time. In my defense, in practice $O(n^2)$ and $O(n^2\log n)$ are usually either both good or both bad.

Comment: That wasn’t my point. What are you sorting by to do this?   Sorting by row sum will not get exactly what you want. For example, if $m$ is 2, choosing i and j means you need to minimize $x_{i,i}+ x_{i,j}+ x_{j,i}+ x_{j,j}$. This means trying all $nCm$ combos which is exponential.

Comment: Since we are effectively removing points, the row and column number we are going to delete are the same. For each $i$ we calculate sum $S_i = M_{i,i}+\sum_{i<j}M_{i,j}+\sum_{i>j}M_{j,i}$ ($O(n^2)$) and store it in the linked list. At each step we find maximum element $S_k$ ($O(n)$), remove it from the list ($O(1)$) and update the list $S'_i = S_k - M_{i,k} - M_{k,i}$ ($O(n)$). We need to do $n/2$ steps. Hmm, looks like my initial estimation was right after all.

Comment: Yeah, that’s the Greedy algorithm - it’s just an approximation - not optimal.

Comment: Yeah, ok. You are right. It looks like NP-hard problem indeed.